# How to convert UTF-8 to Unicode

Tags: bash, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have some file with encoding utf-8 like this

> están

and I want to convert it to something like this

> \u0065\u0073\u0074\u00E1\u006E

How can I make this conversion in bash ?
I installed iconv but I did not managed to convert this

Comment: http://billposer.org/Software/uni2ascii.html and the uconv tool can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ruby you can have:

```
ruby -e "print File.read(ARGV.shift).unpack('U*').map{ |i| '\u' + i.to_s(16).upcase.rjust(4, '0') }.join" your_file
```

Or for strings:

```
ruby -e "puts ARGV.shift.unpack('U*').map{ |i| '\u' + i.to_s(16).upcase.rjust(4, '0') }.join" "your string"
```

Comment: Good it works but what if I need to translate word by word ? How can I translate only a string not whole file

Comment: @Lukap I made an updated. Note that `puts` adds a newline to the end. Replace it with `print` if you don't want it that way.